# Omit directory name in find command

Tags: bash, find

I have a cgi script that calls up a server-side bash script to add a song (entered in a text box on the cgi page) to the rhythmbox queue. 
I'm able to do this with

```
name=`echo "$*" | sed 's/+/*/g'`
rhythmbox-client --enqueue *$name*
```

However the rhythmbox-client --enqueue is case-sensative, meaning if the song/band name has a capital letter, and the user doesn't type that letter with a capital in the cgi script, it won't work.
I also have a seperate command to search my music directory for a given song/band name...

```
search=`find -iname *\$name\*`
if [ "$search" = "" ];
  then echo "No song found."
  else echo "The following songs have been added to the queue: $search"
fi
```

I was wondering if there was any way to remove the directory from the find results, and then I can simply pipe that into a var to use with the --enqueue command, as the find command can be told to ignore captialization senesativity.

Comment: What version of `find` are you using? GNU `find` supports `-printf "%P"`, which prints the name of the file minus the directory argument `find` is searching in, except you don't appear to be using GNU `find` since you aren't specifying a directory to search.

Comment: That worked, but instead of getting 1 line per result found it just strings them all into one long line any way to fix that?

Comment: Just add \n to the format string, to print a newline after each file name.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked, however it didn't help me in the way I wanted, it solved one problem, cleaning up the list is gives back to the user to be just the songname, but it didn't help me with the rhythmbox-client issue, which is it's --enqueue function is case-sensative. I know how to write the result of the find command to a text file, would there be a way to then take that and convert it line by line into variable I can use for the enqueue ?  IE: Take line 1 make it var1 line 2=var 2, ect?  Preferably an array of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.

```
search=`find -iname *\$name\* -type f -printf "%P\n"`
```

Comment: Not sure you understood what I was trying to ask. I'm not trying to make the find only show files, i'm trying to make it NOT show the directory the files are IN, when it gives me the list of results. - chepner gave me the fix for it     find -iname *\$name\* -printf "%P"    but now instead of giving 1 result per line, it mashes them all into one line, making it hard to read. 

The case senesativity is with rhythmbox-client, which can be resolved with find

Comment: ic, add `\n` to get new line in output.